# double Do While looping

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How will I continue this looping? I need to press Y to continue the loop and when I press N it should end the loop . And when I press a different input the loop won't stop until I pressed only Y or N. I'm a beginner Thank you for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class Proj 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int S1 = 0 ;
    String option =null;
     int[][] MT = new int[S1][S1];
    System.out.println("Welcome To The Multiplication Table Program!");
    do{
    System.out.print("Input a number from 1-20: ") ;
    String Num =input.nextLine();

if (Num.equals ("1")){
    S1 = 1 ; MT = timesTable(1,1) ;
}
else if (Num.equals ("2")){
    S1 = 2 ; MT = timesTable(2,2) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("3")){
    S1 = 3 ; 
    MT = timesTable(3,3) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("4")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(4,4) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("5")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(5,5) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("6")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(6,6) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("7")){
    S1 = 2 ;
    MT = timesTable(7,7) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("8")){
    S1 = 2 ;
    MT = timesTable(8,8) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("9")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(9,9) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("10")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(10,10) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("11")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(11,11) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("12")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(12,12) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("13")){
    S1 = 2 ;
    MT = timesTable(13,13) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("14")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(14,14) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("15")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(15,15) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("16")){
    S1 = 2 ;
    MT = timesTable(16,16) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("17")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(17,17) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("18")){
    S1 = 2 ;
    MT = timesTable(18,18) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("19")){
    S1 = 2 ;
    MT = timesTable(19,19) ;
}
    else if (Num.equals ("20")){
    S1 = 2 ; 
    MT = timesTable(20,20) ;
}
else System.out.println("Error! Input a number from 1-20 only!") ;


for(int row = 0; row < MT.length ; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < MT[row].length; column++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%3d ",MT[row][column]);
    }
    System.out.println();

}   
    System.out.println("Enter 'Y' to enter another number \nEnter 'N' to          exit ") ;
    do{
    System.out.print("Y/N: ");
    option = input.nextLine() ;
    if (option.equals ("Y"))
    {
    S1 =  0 ; MT = timesTable(0,0) ;
    }
    else if (option.equals ("N") )
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!") ;
    else System.out.println("Enter Y or N only!") ;

        } while (option.equals("N")) ;
    } while (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) ;

  }


  public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c)
 {
int [][] TT = new int[r][c];
for (int row = 0; row < TT.length ; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < TT[row].length; column++)
    {
        TT[row][column] = (row+1)*(column+1);
    }

}
return TT;
}


}
```

Comment: How did you test this program? Could you clearly mention the steps with actual and expected outputs

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see two loops anywhere, when nothing is indented correctly. I'm not even going to try. **Fix the indentations**, so human beings can follow the code. Maybe that will even make things clear to you too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```html
while(true){
//scan the choice then enter the loop 
while (!choice.equals("N")){
// you should use  "switch case".
}
if(choice.equals("N")){
     System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!") ;
     break;
}
}
```

and you can loop it all.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the 'break' statement

your code:

```
else if (option.equals ("N") )
{
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!") ;

}
```

Updated code:

```
  else if (option.equals ("N") )
{
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!") ;
    break;
}
```

Similarly you can use it in your 'else' statement of your code...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you research abstraction among other programming practises so that your code is more readable and easily understood. But here's a simple method to loop over a process (dependant on the users input (choice)).

```
String choice;
while (!(choice = readLine()).equals("N")){
  if (choice == "Y"){
    //Do the process you wish to loop
  } else{
    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
  }
}
private String readLine(){
  System.out.println("Enter Y to enter another number.\nEnter N to exit.");
  return input.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proj {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int S1 = 0;
        String option = null;
        int[][] MT = new int[S1][S1];
        System.out.println("Welcome To The Multiplication Table Program!");
        boolean validInput = true;
        boolean exitOuterLoop = false;
        do {
            validInput = true; // to reset from second time onwards
            System.out.print("Input a number from 1-20: ");
            String Num = input.nextLine();

            if (Num.equals("1")) {
                S1 = 1;
                MT = timesTable(1, 1);
            } else if (Num.equals("2")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(2, 2);
            } else if (Num.equals("3")) {
                S1 = 3;
                MT = timesTable(3, 3);
            } else if (Num.equals("4")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(4, 4);
            } else if (Num.equals("5")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(5, 5);
            } else if (Num.equals("6")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(6, 6);
            } else if (Num.equals("7")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(7, 7);
            } else if (Num.equals("8")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(8, 8);
            } else if (Num.equals("9")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(9, 9);
            } else if (Num.equals("10")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(10, 10);
            } else if (Num.equals("11")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(11, 11);
            } else if (Num.equals("12")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(12, 12);
            } else if (Num.equals("13")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(13, 13);
            } else if (Num.equals("14")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(14, 14);
            } else if (Num.equals("15")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(15, 15);
            } else if (Num.equals("16")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(16, 16);
            } else if (Num.equals("17")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(17, 17);
            } else if (Num.equals("18")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(18, 18);
            } else if (Num.equals("19")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(19, 19);
            } else if (Num.equals("20")) {
                S1 = 2;
                MT = timesTable(20, 20);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Input a number from 1-20 only!");
                validInput = false;
            }
            if (validInput) {

                for (int row = 0; row < MT.length; row++) {
                    for (int column = 0; column < MT[row].length; column++) {
                        System.out.printf("%3d ", MT[row][column]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                }
                System.out
                        .println("Enter 'Y' to enter another number \nEnter 'N' to exit ");
                do {
                    System.out.print("Y/N: ");
                    option = input.nextLine();
                    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                        S1 = 0;
                        MT = timesTable(0, 0);
                    } else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!");
                        exitOuterLoop = true;
                    }

                    else
                        System.out.println("Enter Y or N only!");

                } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
                        && !option.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
            }

        } while (!exitOuterLoop);

    }

    public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c) {
        int[][] TT = new int[r][c];
        for (int row = 0; row < TT.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < TT[row].length; column++) {
                TT[row][column] = (row + 1) * (column + 1);
            }

        }
        return TT;
    }

}
```

**Note:** Solution I have given here is for the problem you are facing. There are better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Many thanks! My vocabulary on coding is very limited. I only know the basic codes

Comment: It did work. But now I got a new problem . How can I make it as a table? with boxes in every number . like a table . can you help ? ty